# How to Create Distinct Parameter List when Using Stored Proc in SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am new to SSRS and am trying to create a parameter list based on a stored procedure.  I have a stored procedure which contains a field for Department.  Many of the results of the stored procedure will be for the same department.  However, when I display the parameter list I only want each department to appear once.

So far, I haven't had any luck.

Changing the stored procedure is not an option for me, but I am open to creating a 2nd Data Set based on the original Data Set.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
MB

Answer (score 1):

I assuming that for some reason, you can't simply query your database for a list of distinct departments, if you can, just do that in your dataset. If not do something like this.

Let's assume your stored prod produces output something like

```
DepartmentID Department Job             Value
1            Sales      Sell something  100
1            Sales      Sell more stuff 200
2            IT         Break things    -50
2            IT         Fix stuff       123
```

In your dataset use this as the query...

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (DepartmentID int, Department varchar(20), Job varchar(100), Value int)

INSERT INTO @table
    EXEC dbo.MyStoredProc

SELECT DISTINCT DepartmentID, Department FROM @table
```

This will return

```
DepartmentID, Department
1             Sales
2             IT
```

You can then use this to populated the Available Values for your parameter.